# Different outer tick sizes between top and bottom x axes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the following example the outer tick sizes (and therefore the path heights) differ between the bottom and the top axis. Could someone explain the reason why? I couldn't find any relevant answer.

```js
var width = 100,
    height = 100,
    margin = 30;
    
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
     .attr('width', width)
     .attr('height', height);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 10])
    .range([margin, width - margin]);

// Add the Axis
svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height - margin) + ")")
   .attr("class", "xAxis")
 .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
   .tickValues([0, 10])
   );
   
svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + ( margin) + ")")
   .attr("class", "xAxis")
 .call(d3.axisTop(x)
   .tickValues([0, 10])
   );
```

```css
.xAxis path{
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}

.xAxis text{
  fill: black;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<body></body>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any difference? They are exactly the same (mirror image) to me. You can actually see this in the paths: `M30.5,6V0.5H70.5V6` and `M30.5,-6V0.5H70.5V-6`.

Comment: No, they are not. There's a minimum of 1 px difference (depending on the screen resolution and zoom). Despite the fact that the path coordinates appear to be the same, if you inspect the element (path height) you can see the difference. You can also see that if you superimpose the inner ticks. You will see that the inner tick position on the main axes differs.

Comment: for example add .xAxis line{
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}